# add before and after the sidebar active custom html automatically in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add html code before and after the active side sidebar, without having to touch the theme, ie, making from my own plugin, or through the functions.php file.

Can this be done?

Thanks !!

Comment: take a look at this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/hooking-a-function-onto-the-sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: If you want to insert code you need either something you can hook into (WordPress Action reference) or filter (WordPress filter reference) or you need to insert a custom line of code into your Theme which you can hook into or which includes the custom code.

The purpose of a Theme is to provide the desired output for WordPress therefore it must be either adjustable or should provide hooks, widget areas, dynamic sidebars or something similar in order to customize it as much as needed (anyway your Theme most probably offers one of these possibilities).